# Extract form data and send to my database with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to extract data from a html form and send to my database. I'm using node.js, mongodb and mongoose.

i have a form like this:

```
<form>                                      
   <label for="name">Nome:</label>
   <input type="text" id="name">

    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    input type="text" id="email">

    <button id="send" type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

My code to save is ready, i just don't know how extract the values of the fields.

This is my route:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('client');
});
```

And i have this code ready:

```
var person = {
    name: req.params.name,
    email: req.params.email
};

var data = new dataSchema(person);

data.save(function (error, data){
    if(error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.json(data);
    }
    else {
        res.json(data);
    }
});
```

The rest of the code (new schema, mongoose.model, etc .. is perfect ok). What remains now is to extract the fields of the form.

UPDATE..

rdegges there is something wrong, this is my code now:

```
    <form method="post">
       <label for="name">Nome:</label>
       <input type="text" id="name">

        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="text" id="email">

        <button id="send" type="submit">Send</button>
    </form>
```

and in my routes:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));


router.get('/login', function(req, res) {
  res.render('client/index');
});

router.post('/login', function(req, res) {
  res.json(req.body); // handle the user form data
  console.log(req.body);
});
```

There is something wrong? The object is empty.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `body-parser` middleware, like so:

```
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post('/', function(req, res) {
  res.json(req.body); // req.body is your form data
});
```

If you do the above, you'll be able to use `req.body` inside your code to access the form data, which you can then pass into mongoose to save your model.

Also, you'll most likely want to modify your HTML form to look like this:

```
<form method="post">
</form>
```

This means you'll create a POST request to your server, which is what you'll use in your route.

Here's an example:

```
app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
  // render the form
  res.render('login');
});

app.post('/login', function(req, res) {
  res.json(req.body); // handle the user form data
});
```

Comment: i understood, but.. this req.body is empty when i load the page.. how make work after the user submit the form??

Comment: Just modified my answer to include more information about this =)

Comment: Do you have `app.use('/', router);` at the bottom of your JS file?

Comment: nop, i have that in my app.js, in the bottom of the routes i have module.exports = router;

Comment: It should be in your app.js at the very bottom =)

Comment: yes, i have.. look: http://i.imgur.com/lZVdbY3.png . I'm using two routes files, one for my server and one for my client.. the routes is working fine :B

Comment: maybe i miss something.. is working know.. very very very much @rdegges.